# Which Bach chorale preludes are appropriate for different times of the liturgical year?

Tags: j-s-bach, organ, church-music

Is there a guide available that assigns all of Bach's organ chorale preludes to appropriate times in the liturgical year?

Bach himself began such a catalog in the *Orgelbüchlein*.  That's the sort of thing I am looking for, but for all of the liturgical works including the Neumeister chorale preludes.

Comment: Actually, if you include the "ghosts", the Orgelbüchlein is rather thorough. A lot of those "ghosts" are covered by his other output.

Comment: Does http://www.bach-cantatas.com/LCY/index.htm have everything on your want-list?

Comment: I love these kinds of questions and wish I knew enough about the liturgical year to offer a reasonable answer.  But alas I don't.

Comment: You might want to ask on http://christianity.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Given user16935's response and the easy accessibility of the Orgelbüchlein, would it be appropriate to start a community Wiki with the Orgelbüchlein?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of the [Orgelbüchlein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_organ_compositions_by_Johann_Sebastian_Bach#Chorale_Preludes), which sounds like what you're looking for (or at least might be a start):

**Advent**

- BWV 599 – Nun komm, der Heiden Heiland
- BWV 600 – Gott, durch deine Güte, or: Gottes Sohn ist kommen
- BWV 601 – Herr Christ, der einge Gottessohn, or: Herr Gott, nun sei gepreiset (also in the Neumeister Collection)
- BWV 602 – Lob sei dem allmächtigen Gott

**Christmas**

- BWV 603 – Puer natus in Bethlehem
- BWV 604 – Gelobet seist du, Jesu Christ
- BWV 605 – Der Tag, der ist so freudenreich
- BWV 606 – Vom Himmel hoch, da komm ich her
- BWV 607 – Vom Himmel kam der Engel Schar
- BWV 608 – In dulci jubilo
- BWV 609 – Lobt Gott, ihr Christen, allzugleich
- BWV 610 – Jesu, meine Freude
- BWV 611 – Christum wir sollen loben schon
- BWV 612 – Wir Christenleut'

**New Year**

- BWV 613 – Helft mir Gottes Güte preisen
- BWV 614 – Das alte Jahr vergangen ist
- BWV 615 – In dir ist Freude

**Epiphany**

- BWV 616 – Mit Fried und Freud ich fahr dahin
- BWV 617 – Herr Gott, nun schleuß den Himmel auf

**Lent**

- BWV 618 – O Lamm Gottes, unschuldig
- BWV 619 – Christe, du Lamm Gottes
- BWV 620 – Christus, der uns selig macht
- BWV 620a – Christus, der uns selig macht (older version)
- BWV 621 – Da Jesus an dem Kreuze stund
- BWV 622 – O Mensch, bewein dein Sünde groß
- BWV 623 – Wir danken dir, Herr Jesu Christ
- BWV 624 – Hilf Gott, daß mir's gelinge

**Easter**

- BWV 625 – Christ lag in Todesbanden
- BWV 626 – Jesus Christus, unser Heiland
- BWV 627 – Christ ist erstanden
- BWV 628 – Erstanden ist der heil'ge Christ
- BWV 629 – Erschienen ist der herrliche Tag
- BWV 630 – Heut triumphieret Gottes Sohn

**Pentecost**

- BWV 631 – Komm, Gott Schöpfer, Heiliger Geist
- BWV 631a – Komm, Gott Schöpfer, Heiliger Geist (older version)
- BWV 632 – Herr Jesu Christ, dich zu uns wend'
- BWV 633 – Liebster Jesu, wir sind hier
- BWV 634 – Liebster Jesu, wir sind hier (earlier version of BWV 633)

**Catechism hymns**

- BWV 635 – Dies sind die heil'gen zehn Gebot'
- BWV 636 – Vater unser im Himmelreich
- BWV 637 – Durch Adams Fall ist ganz verderbt
- BWV 638 – Es ist das Heil uns kommen her